# Is there a way to setting delay time after reach number of request in a minute in PHP?

Tags: php, web-services, http, request

Im using an api there are limited number of request time. In my system there will be lots of user for using. Can i do set time to each request after 20 request in a min in Php or symfony?

Comment: Your question is very hard to understand. Do you want to limit the number of requests your users can make?

Comment: Sorry for my english first. My question is the function if get 20 request in min, there will be delay little bit . It will continue each minute depends on request. If the function has 20 request in a minute, next minute there will be delay